# Responsive design with reactable tables in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have saved reactable tables that I read into an R Markdown document. The R Markdown document is part of a website that is built with `blogdown` and Hugo.

The tables, T1 and T2 are narrow enough to each fit OK on a mobile device. Side by side they are too wide.

On a big screen I want the tables to be displayed side-by-side, in two columns.

T1   T2

On a mobile phone, I'd like the tables to be like so:

T1

T2

RMarkdown

````
---
title: "Table Test"
description: "Responsive design with two reactable tables."
categories: []
tags: []
output:
  html_document:
    includes: header.html
  
---

<h1>My Tables</h1>

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library("qs")
library("reactable")

T1 <- qread("/data/T1.qs")
T2 <- qread("/data/T2.qs")

T1
T2
```
````

I *think* all I want is to have the reactable tables be cells in a responsive HTML table of 1 row and 2 columns. How is this done?